# How do you check relations in mathematically?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Given that $A=\{A_{i} \mid i \in I\}$ and $B=\{B_{i} \mid i \in I\}$. Show that the following statements are relation such as $ \bigcup_i A_{i} \subset \bigcup_i B_{i}$ if every $i \in I $ and $A_{i} \subset B_{i}$.

How do you check relations in mathematically ? Please help me. Thanks your good idea.

Comment: To show that $X\subset Y$, follow the following template: Suppose that $x\in X$ and prove that $x\in Y$.  In your case, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

We are proving: if $A_i\subset B_i$ then $\bigcup_iA_i\subset\bigcup_iB_i$.

Take $x\in\bigcup_iA_i$ and deduce that there is at least some $A_k$ such that
$x\in A_k$. So 
$$x\in A_k\subset B_k\subset\bigcup_iB_i.$$
Hence   $\bigcup_iA_i\subset\bigcup_iB_i$.